# FFMPEG sws_scale Crash on Android

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I have an app that convert images to video, in Google Play I see the following crash (which the only details I get is the name of the function and I don't understand the rest):

```
backtrace:
#00 pc 0000cc78 /data/app-lib/com.myapp-1/libswscale.so (sws_scale+204)
#01 pc 000012af /data/app-lib/com.myapp-1/libffmpeg.so (OpenImage+322)

code around pc:
79065c58 e58d8068 e58d2070 e58d3074 059d00b0
```

The code point to the function `sws_scale`, the code works almost all the time on my device (Nexus 5) but I see a lot of reports even with the same device with that issue. Any idea why this could happen?

```
AVFrame* OpenImage(const char* imageFileName, int W_VIDEO, int H_VIDEO, int* numBytes)
{
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;
    AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx;
    AVCodec *pCodec;
    AVFrame *pFrame;
    int frameFinished;
    uint8_t *buffer;
    AVPacket packet;
    int srcBytes;

    AVFrame* frame2 = NULL;// scaled frame
    uint8_t* frame2_buffer;
    struct SwsContext *resize;

    if(av_open_input_file(&pFormatCtx, imageFileName, NULL, 0, NULL)!=0)
    {
        LOGI("Can't open image file '%s'\n", imageFileName);
        return NULL;
    }
    //dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, imageFileName, 0);
    if (av_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx) < 0)
    {
        LOGI("Can't find stream info.");
        return NULL;
    }
    pCodecCtx = pFormatCtx->streams[0]->codec;
    pCodecCtx->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

    // Find the decoder for the video stream
    pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
    if (!pCodec)
    {
        LOGI("Codec not found\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Open codec
    if(avcodec_open(pCodecCtx, pCodec)<0)
    {
        LOGI("Could not open codec\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    pFrame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
    if (!pFrame)
    {
        LOGI("Can't allocate memory for AVFrame\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Determine required buffer size and allocate buffer
    srcBytes = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_YUV420P, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);
    buffer = (uint8_t *) av_malloc(srcBytes * sizeof(uint8_t));
    avpicture_fill((AVPicture *) pFrame, buffer, PIX_FMT_YUV420P, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

    // Read frame
    if (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0)
    {
        int ret;
//      if(packet.stream_index != 0)
//          continue;
        ret = avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);
        if (ret > 0)
        {
            //LOGI("Frame is decoded, size %d\n", ret);
            pFrame->quality = 4;

            // Create another frame for resized result
            frame2 = avcodec_alloc_frame();
            *numBytes = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_YUV420P, W_VIDEO, H_VIDEO);
            frame2_buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(*numBytes * sizeof(uint8_t));
            avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)frame2, frame2_buffer, PIX_FMT_YUV420P, W_VIDEO, H_VIDEO);

            // Get resize context
            resize = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, PIX_FMT_YUV420P, W_VIDEO, H_VIDEO, PIX_FMT_YUV420P, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);

            // frame2 should be filled with resized samples
            ret = sws_scale(resize, (const uint8_t* const*)pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, frame2->data, frame2->linesize);
            sws_freeContext(resize);
        }
        else
            LOGI("Error [%d] while decoding frame: %s\n", ret, strerror(AVERROR(ret)));
    }
    av_free(pFrame);
    av_free_packet(&packet);
    avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);
    //av_free(pCodecCtx);
    av_close_input_file(pFormatCtx);
    return frame2;
}
```

Comment: PC is the Program Counter: `#01 pc 000012af`. Its the instruction pointer. What function and line number does `000012af` correspond to in libffmpeg.so?

Comment: How can I find out?. Sorry I'm not C/C++ developer and tried looking online couldn't figure out.

Comment: I just started a bounty on [native crash collection and symbolication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993228/native-crash-collection-and-symbolication). I'm a C/C++ guy, and I did not quite understand all the details of the answer (or lacked the knowledge to understand all the details).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your `avcodec_decode_video2`, do not check `ret` only. You need to check `frameFinished` too. if `frameFinished == 0`, your frame should not be used (because not filled). I do not know for images, but when you decode video, it happens very often. You need to read the next packet and give to the next call of `avcodec_decode_video2`.

On a side note: why are you forcing `pCodecCtx->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P`? It is automatically set to the correct format by `av_find_stream_info`, and you should use it as `sws_getContext` parameter.

Last thing: no need to fill your `pFrame`with `avpicture_fill`. You only need to `av_frame_alloc()` it, and `avcodec_decode_video2` will take care of filling it.

Answer (score 1):

After this line

```
*numBytes = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_YUV420P, W_VIDEO, H_VIDEO);
```

You have not checked the return value.

In the `avpicture_get_size describe`:

```
"Returns:
the computed picture buffer size or a negative error code in case of error"
```

When you check the `*numBytes` (and `srcBytes`, `buffer`, `frame2_buffer`) value(s), maybe it will be better...

Comment: Is this possibly the cause of the crash happen or just an improvement on the code, since it's not the "sws_scale" line I'm wondering if this could solve the issue.